# Import object by ExportMetadata attribute in MEF

Tags: c#, mef

I would like to ask, is it possible to import some object by ExportMetadata value ? For example, string.
Or
If I declared some Export objects by name and type can I import all of them by just only type ?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to defer the creation of the part through either `Lazy` or `ExportFactory`.  E.g, given my sample type:

```
[Export(typeof(ILogger)), ExportMetadata("Name", "Console")]
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{

}
```

I would need a metadata interface:

```
public interface INamedMetadata
{
  string Name { get; }
}
```

Then I could import many instances as:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(ILogger))]
IEnumerable<Lazy<ILogger, INamedMetadata>> Loggers { get; set; }
```

And make a selection:

```
public ILogger GetLogger(string name)
{
  return Loggers
    .Where(l => l.Metadata.Name.Equals(name))
    .Select(l => l.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: To add to this, the main benefit of this is that within the list of possible `ILoggers`, only the selected `ILogger` is instantiated at any one time. The others are available for use, but instances won't be created until `l.Value` is called.